# Mongoengine + MongoMock do not return data as expected

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-restful, mongomock

I am trying to test a response made by the controller. The response is different when I am running it through **gunicorn** vs a **testFramework**

### My `server.py` looks like the following:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/pub')
api = Api(app, catch_all_404s=True)

connect('myapp', host='mongomock://localhost')

api.add_resource(IndexController, "/")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=debug)
```

### My `IndexController` looks like:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from myapp.models.User import User

class IndexController(Resource):
  """
  This controller shows all the Users
  """

  @classmethod
  def get(cls):
    """
    Simple GET call for /
    """
    data = []
    for user in User.objects:
        data.append({
            "name": user.name,
            "location": user.location
        })
```

### The `User` object:

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

class User(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=200, required=True, unique=True)
    location = PointField(default=[0,0])
```

### My `IndexControllerTest`:

```
class IndexControllerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    This is the default controller Base class which
    sets up the server app and has handy asserts to make
    life easier when testing the controllers
    """

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Set up a global instance of the controller
        """
        self.app = server.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        conn = get_connection()
        conn.myapp.user.drop()
        #Have to do this because it does not clear the unique index

    def assertGet(self, path, data):
        """
        This will run a GET request and test the output
        """
        response = self.app.get(path)

        #print str(response.get_data())
        #print flask.json.dumps(response.data)

        parsed = flask.json.loads(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(parsed, data)

    def test_get_returns_one_user(self):
        """
        When I call a get I should get Users with thier data
        """

        user = User(name="muse")
        user.save()

        self.assertGet(
            "/",
            [ 
              { 
                "name": "muse", 
                "location": [ 0, 0 ]
              } 
            ],
            status_code=200
        )
```

---

### Output through `gunicorn` which is what I want!:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Hello",
    "location": [
      52.201962,
      0.128145
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "World",
    "location": [
      0,
      0
    ]
  }
]
```

### Output from my test:

```
...
First differing element 0:
{u'name': u'muse', u'location': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [0, 0]}}
{'name': 'muse', 'location': [0, 0]}

- [{u'location': {u'coordinates': [0, 0], u'type': u'Point'}, u'name': u'muse'}]
+ [{'location': [0, 0], 'name': 'muse'}]
```

---

*What? Why? Where? Who? @£*$@$%*&£$(%&£$*((*& Madness!*

I would expect the `flask_restfull` API to ensure in both cases the output is the same

Comment: FYI the mogomock tag refers to this https://github.com/vmalloc/mongomock, mongoengine uses it as a mocking framework

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, my DB had the following from a previous insert:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f6966f007502d9952babde"),
        "name" : "World",
        "created" : ISODate("2016-03-26T14:02:23.546Z"),
        "location" : [
                50.201962,
                1.128145
        ]
}
```

But I expect it to be (The tests were correct):

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f6966f007502d9952babde"),
        "name" : "World",
        "created" : ISODate("2016-03-26T14:02:23.546Z"),
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        50.201962,
                        1.128145
                ]
        }
}
```

So my tests were correct but, my db was reflecting bad therefore it won't come back as expected. I assumed if the data was wrong the mongoengine would throw some sort of error but, good to know that it does not.